# Find sample documents in mongo where a nested field matches a value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have millions of records in collection and here are some sample documents

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("003fjasf0234j03j0349")
    FirstLayer: {
        SecondLayer: {
            Status: {
                9428f:{
                    active: "Active"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    _id: ObjectId("qg3o4034034nr34343")
    FirstLayer: {
        SecondLayer: {
            Status: {
                9428f:{
                    active: "Active"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    _id: ObjectId("293je2odjojwe0f23")
    FirstLayer: {
        SecondLayer: {
            Status: {
                00fekw:{
                    active: "Not Active"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fetch a few sample documents from monogdb where the `active: "Active"`.
I came up with this:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([
  {$match:{"FirstLayer.SecondLayer.Status.9428f.active": "Active"}},
  {$sample:{size: 50}}
  ])
```

It's working but the issue is the sub document inside `Stauts {}` have different names for documents (ex: "9428f", "00fekw" in the given sample documents). So I can't hard code the path to "active" field.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Comment: @turivishal Both solutions work. Problem is I have 20+ collections and each collection contains millions of records. So fetching a sample from each collection taking quite some time.

Comment: yes it would take time, because we don't create index in dynamic field, it is possible in array but its not possible in dynamic object.

Comment: @turivishal "active" field would always be at the same place. Is there a way that I can directly reach to active like "FirstLayer.SecondLayer.Status.9428f.active" but instead, I can replace the dynamic subdocument name 9428f with some placeholder document name like "FirstLayer.SecondLayer.Status.xxxxx.active" so I can directly use match and fetch records quickly?

Comment: no its not possible to directly access active field or to replace dynamic field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is there any straight way to handle this situation in MongoDB,

You can try,

**Approach 1:**

- `$set` to add a field `Status` to assign value of `Status` after converting it to array in key-value format using `$objectToArray`
- `$match` match Status condition
- `$unset` remove `Status` field because its not needed
- `$sample` your documents

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { Status: { $objectToArray: "$FirstLayer.SecondLayer.Status" } } },
  { $match: { "Status.v.active": "Active" } },
  { $unset: "Status" },
  { $sample: { size: 50 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2-fQtZBuVqb)

**Approach 2:**

Condition match with expression `$expr`, you can use aggregation operators in condition,

- `$let` to create a vars `status` to get status array from object and `in` filter status array and get `active` status,
- `$size` get size of above filter result
- expression will check if size is not zero then return result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $let: {
          vars: { status: { $objectToArray: "$FirstLayer.SecondLayer.Status" } },
          in: {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$$status",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$this.v.active", "Active"] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sample: { size: 50 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vSewtEWEPz6)